# How to get input for a game loop in haskell

Tags: haskell

http://pastebin.com/2CS1k1Zq

In this game i need to get step the game forward every half a second or so while occasionally getting input to change direction. These too things seem impossible to do with haskell is there a way to do it? Currently I am having an mv tread stall exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write a game loop in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285691/how-do-i-write-a-game-loop-in-haskell)

Comment: No because I understand the basics of how to make a gameloop what i dont understand is how you delay your game or make it step through in time. Also how to get input.

Comment: You're probably going to need an observer to check for keydowns. How to do it depends on your platform, you might need to do some "FFI-ing". Once that's covered, your actual game loop could look like a standard Haskell game loop. And to make it playable, don't forget to delay the rendering part (e.g. make the thread sleep between game-steps, but make sure you can still get input!). It would be helpful if you could mention your platform and even tag it (especially since this seems to be a console game).

Comment: What is FFL ing? And i am running on a windows machine

Comment: I mean using the FFI (Foreign Function Interface). I suggest you learn what it is (within Haskell, of course). You could use it to import (impure) system calls (e.g. from the Win32 API) that will tell you when a key is pressed.

Comment: @KyleMcKean By the way, when you're responding to someone in a comment that isn't to his question or answer, make sure to tag his name with a "@", like I did at the start of this comment. This will notify the person that you replied. So in this particular comment this isn't necessary because this is a comment to your question (but I did for demonstration).

Comment: Sounds like this answer is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143041/block-until-keypress-or-given-time-of-day

Answer (score 2):

Update: Found the `hWaitForInput` function in `System.IO` which is essentially the same as `waitFor`.

Here is some code largely based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9143153/866915).

The main difference I made is that the thread waiting for a key press does not perform the `getChar` directly. The result communicated in the `MVar` is an indication of timeout or that a key press has occurred. It is the responsibility of the main thread to actually get the character. This prevents a possible race condition in case the char reading thread is killed between getting the character and putting it into the `MVar`.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import Data.Maybe
import System.IO
import Control.Exception

data Event = CharReady | TimedOut

withRawStdin :: IO a -> IO a
withRawStdin = bracket uncook restore . const
  where
    uncook = do
        oldBuffering <- hGetBuffering stdin
        oldEcho <- hGetEcho stdin
        hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
        hSetEcho stdin False
        return (oldBuffering, oldEcho)
    restore (oldBuffering, oldEcho) = do
        hSetBuffering stdin oldBuffering
        hSetEcho stdin oldEcho

waitFor :: Int -> IO Event
waitFor delay = do
    done <- newEmptyMVar
    withRawStdin . bracket (start done) cleanUp $ \_ -> takeMVar done
  where
    start done = do
        t1 <- forkIO $ hLookAhead stdin >> putMVar done CharReady
        t2 <- forkIO $ threadDelay delay >> putMVar done TimedOut
        return (t1, t2)
    cleanUp (t1, t2) = do
        killThread t1
        killThread t2

loop state = do
  if state <= 0
    then putStrLn "Game over."
    else do putStrLn $ "Rounds to go: " ++ show state
            e <- waitFor 3000000
            case e of
              TimedOut -> do putStrLn "Too late!"; loop state
              CharReady -> do c <- getChar -- should not block
                              if c == 'x'
                                then do putStrLn "Good job!"; loop (state-1)
                                else do putStrLn "Wrong key"; loop state

main = loop 3
```

Comment: Haskell newbie here, this helped me, thank you. I tried using hWaitForInput but getChar becomes blocking then, don't know why.